# Apollo useQuery does not always trigger re-render of function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

This is my functional component that makes use of `useQuery` from `@apollo/client`:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { data } = useQuery<MarketScannerSearchProps>(
    MARKET_SCANNER_SEARCH_PROPS_QUERY,
    {
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        console.log("completed", data)
      },
    }
  )
  console.log("data", data)

  // ... rest of function + return rendered result
}
```

I get this in my console:

```
data undefined
data undefined

completed {marketScannerSearchProps: {…}}
```

why isn't there a `data {marketScannerSearchProps: {…}}` at the end?

This is not always reproducible, only happens every 5th reload or so of my app. This is how it looks when it works:

```
data undefined
data {marketScannerSearchProps: {…}}
completed {marketScannerSearchProps: {…}}
```

So somehow the 2nd time the component is rendered the data is there, but not always, and if the data isn't there by the 2nd render, it never updates it afterwards.

Shouldn't apollo trigger a re-render every time once the query completes? What am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I think this issue might be gone now. I closed and opened Chrome Dev Tools a few times, and now it seems to be gone. Could it be Apollo client side caching getting messed up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

It's an issue with React Dev Tools (I've experimented with incrementally removing various chrome extensions and consistently found that React Dev Tools is the culprit). **The best solution, for now, is to disable the React Dev Tools extension, close the Chrome Dev Tools, reload the page, and then everything will work.**

Since this is an issue with React Dev Tools, I'll create a GitHub issue on their repo and update this answer with a link to it so anyone in the future can find it.